# How can I flip a live section with the Revit API

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I would like to be able to flip a live section using the Revit 2017 API.  It would be the equivalent of the UI feature seen in my images below.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

I've tried using the built-in `ElementTransformUtils.MirrorElement` but that will only create a second section marker with a second section view.  Is there any way that I can achieve this using the Revit API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution to my post [How can I flip a section using the Revit 2017 API](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/how-can-i-flip-a-section-using-the-revit-2017-api/m-p/6876853#M21138) on the Revit API forum.  It turns out that I overlooked the plural `ElementTransformUtils.MirrorElements` function which I assumed was almost exactly the same as the singular `ElementTransformUtils.MirrorElement` except for doing multiple element mirrors instead of a single mirror.  The plural `ElementTransformUtils.MirrorElements` has a `bool mirrorCopies` parameter that you can set to `false` which will force the original section to be mirrored instead of just making mirrored copy of the original.  Here are the two function signatures side-by-side:

```
void MirrorElement(
  Document document, 
  ElementId elementToMirror, 
  Plane plane
);

IList<ElementId> MirrorElements(
  Document document, 
  ICollection<ElementId> elementsToMirror, 
  Plane plane, 
  bool mirrorCopies
);
```

My code ends up looking like this (with `elementsToMirror` only containing a single element):

```
ElementTransformUtils.MirrorElements(document, elementsToMirror, mirrorPlane, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `CropBox` property of the `ViewSection` object. The Z components of the `Min` and `Max` properties should be inverted.

Comment: Yes, could you please share a code sample?  This was the road I was headed down before I got a response from the Revit API forums.  Also, one of the people responding to my post there stated that setting `mirrorCopies` to `false` (as per my answer) didn't work for them.  I'm wondering if my answer doesn't work for older versions of Revit.